# Regex match method is not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a method that simply checks a text file for several strings - although a few strings are not being picked up as a match even though they are present in the text document. I have included the offending string this is not being found in this example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str = @"1009 10.32.0.28 03/05/2012 09:11:48 The license expires in 1192 day(s).";
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"event_history.txt");
        string allRead = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        string regMatch = str;
        if (Regex.IsMatch(allRead, regMatch))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("found\n");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("not found\n");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

}
```

**event_history.txt**

```
1009 10.32.0.28 03/05/2012 09:11:48 The license expires in 1192 day(s).
```

If I replace the regex match with say "testing" and then add "testing" to the text file, it picks it up as a match no problem :S

Comment: You are using Regex in a wrong way. Why not to use string.Contains?

Comment: A lot of that punctuation has to be escaped if using REGEX. If you know exactly what you're looking for, us Contains() as ie. said. Otherwise, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx for some explanations

Comment: You might want to actually learn regular expressions first, before you use them. They are a whole language in disguise to make your life just a little more fun. If you are into masochistic notions of fun, that is ;)

Answer (score 1):

regMatch=str and str is not a regex. Why are you using RegEx? You should be using something similar to

```
".*The license expires in [0-9]* day(s).".
```

Taking it further, for all entries for IP 10.23.0.28:

```
"1009 10\.32\.0\.28 ..\/..\/.... ..\:..\:.. The license expires in [0-9]* day(s)."
```

Using file regex.txt for example:

```
$ cat regex.txt
1009 10.32.0.28 03/05/2012 09:11:48 The license expires in 1192 day(s).
1009 10.32.0.28 04/05/2012 09:11:48 The license expires in 1192 day(s).
1009 10.32.0.29 04/05/2012 09:11:48 The license expires in 1192 day(s).
1009 10.32.0.30 04/05/2012 09:11:48 The license expires in 1192 day(s).
```

Results are:

```
$ grep "1009 10\.32\.0\.28 ..\/..\/.... ..\:..\:.. The license expires in [0-9]* day(s)." regex.txt
1009 10.32.0.28 03/05/2012 09:11:48 The license expires in 1192 day(s).
1009 10.32.0.28 04/05/2012 09:11:48 The license expires in 1192 day(s).
```

> if that is the string you always want to check for (1009, 1192 days, ip address and date 
>   always static).

Use:

```
".... 10\.32\.0\.28 04\/05\/2012 ..\:..\:.. The license expires in 1192 day(s)."
```

Comment: This is quite greedy, it ignores the other text the OP posted, does not care if there are not any numbers present and doesn't escape the parenthesis or the last `.`.

Comment: Yes you have to add additional regex to pin point exact entries. YOu can certainly take this further by removing wildcard in the prefix.

Answer (score 1):

The `str` is not the correct regex for what you are trying to accomplish. For example the `.` means any character and the parenthesis around `s` are a grouping and will not be captured. You actually just need to check if `allRead` contains `str` if that is the string you always want to check for (1009, 1192 days, ip address and date always static).

```
string str = @"1009 10.32.0.28 03/05/2012 09:11:48 The license expires in 1192 day(s).";
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"event_history.txt");
string allRead = sr.ReadToEnd();

if(allRead.Contains(str))
{
    Console.WriteLine("found\n");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("not found\n");
}
```

If you are looking for a regex that captures non static values here you go

```
string str = @"\d+ \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3} \d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} The license expires in \d+ day\(s\)\.";
```

Comment: Well, it is a valid regexp, but it doesn't do what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `Regex.IsMatch` as `String.Contains`. Regular expressions have their own syntax so that won't work (in general).

In your particular example, you need to escape the parantheses around `s`, because the regular expression engine will not match them as they are written now, they're the capture operator. The dots also should be escaped, although ironically regex dots do match dots. So:

```
string str = @"1009 10\.32\.0\.28 03/05/2012 09:11:48 The license expires in 1192 day\(s\)\.";
```

Comment: I think it would be easier to keep the string as it is and use `Regex.Escape()`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the regex isn't matching is because ( and ) are special characters in a regex.  They represent a grouping, a value that you want to reference later.  To change them to just regular characters, append a \ right in front of them.  So your regex should look like

```
@"1009 10.32.0.28 03/05/2012 09:11:48 The license expires in 1192 day\(s\)."
```